# angular ui google map marker not working mozilla

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

comming this error . can you help me? how to solve this? but CHROME browser is working fine . mozilla not working

```
 Error: Promise.defer is not a function
    c@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:5:6375
    l</j.prototype.createMarkersFromScratch/</<@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:7:437
    e@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:5:5958
    l</j.prototype.createMarkersFromScratch@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:7:384
    a/<@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:6:29405
    j@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:6:31044
    e</f.prototype.link/</<@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:8:5487
    Ae/e/l.promise.then/F@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular/angular.min.js:100:178
    Ae/f/<.then/<@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular/angular.min.js:101:350
    Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular/angular.min.js:112:64
    Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular/angular.min.js:109:160
    Zd/this.$get</k.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular/angular.min.js:112:396
    p</d.prototype.link/</</</<@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:8:941
    Vt/<@http://localhost:1337/plugin/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js:29:107
    .debounceNow@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:5:13771
    p</d.prototype.link/</</<@http://localhost:1337/plugin/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js:8:909
    T.trigger@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/16/main.js:18:234
    rU/<@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/16/main.js line 59 > eval line 36 > eval:15:401
    T.trigger@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/16/main.js:18:234
    gf@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/16/main.js:22:260
    N.set@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/16/main.js:21:851
    cw[H].A@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/16/main.js line 59 > eval:123:963
    S/<@https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/20/16/main.js:16:260
```

My angularjs version: AngularJS v1.2.26
angular-google-maps 2.0.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A quick lookup on the Git](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/search?q=Promise.defer&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) of the project indicates that this issue is due to the fact the Chrome supports the native use of Promise and FF does not.
The developer suggested that you include the library bluebird in your project but this was a year ago and it seems that is it no longer necessary.

I also use the angular-google-maps directive with no problem on FF (without bluebird). You may need to upgrade your library to the latest version and make sure that you include every dependencies listed in the readme.

Could you provide information about your angular and your library version ?

Comment: i have given my angularjs version

Comment: your version is one year old, could you get and try with the latest (2.2.x)) ?

Comment: ya ok how to download it? can you send any link?

Comment: Get it with bower (angular-google-maps) or download it on the github : https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps (dist folder).....

Comment: ya thanks. i will update my angular map version. Is it solve?

Comment: Well, you tell me, I can't know for sure. Upgrade it and test your code again.

Comment: Hi,  i have used this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/master/dist/angular-google-maps.min.js

Comment: show this error Uncaught TypeError: "google-maps".ns is not a function

Comment: Make sure you have also installed and updated every dependencies listed in the readme of the library and you made sure that you app actually includes the library : angular.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);. If you need extensive help to include or update a library please open another question.